# How can I flip a sprite in SFML?

Tags: sprites, sfml

I am facing the same problem although the sprite flips but only one time after that it does not flips at all.

Here is the code snippet:

```
void Doodle::moveLeft()
{
    if(d_Right)
        d_Sprite.setScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
    d_Left = true;
}

void Doodle::moveRight()
{
    if(d_Left==false)
        d_Sprite.setScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
    d_Right = true;
}

void Doodle::stopLeft()
{
    d_Left = false;
}

void Doodle::stopRight()
{
    d_Right = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void Doodle::moveLeft() { if(d_Right) d_Sprite.setScale(-1.0f, 1.0f); d_Left = true; }

void Doodle::moveRight() { if(d_Left==false) d_Sprite.setScale(-1.0f, 1.0f); d_Right = true; }
```

This code is exactly the same, specifically: d_Sprite.setScale(-1.0f, 1.0f), this only flips it one way, you have to change this to flip it back.

Answer (score 1):

The [setScale](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Transformable.php#aaec50b46b3f41b054763304d1e727471) function overwrites the previous scale. You just need to set the scale to 1 to get the original sprite.

```
void Doodle::moveLeft()
{
    d_Sprite.setScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
}

void Doodle::moveRight()
{
    d_Sprite.setScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```